# How to Expose Cordova Plugins to Svelte App?

Tags: cordova, svelte

I have cordova app with svelte inside, but i have problem with exposing cordova.plugins from cordova to svelte

Here what i tried
index.js

```
const app = {


// Application Constructor
  initialize: function () {
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", this.onDeviceOffline, false);
  },
  onDeviceOffline: function () {
    app.receivedEvent("No Internet");
    PHONEGAP.isOffline = true;
  },
  onDeviceReady: function () {
    app.receivedEvent("deviceready");
    console.log(cordova.plugins); // this return object plugins
    if (cordova && cordova.plugins) {
      PHONEGAP.plugins = cordova.plugins;
      PHONEGAP.platform = cordova.platformId;
    }
},
  cordovaObject: function () {
    return cordova;
  },
  // Update DOM on a Received Event
  receivedEvent: function (id) {
    console.log("Received Event: " + id);
  },
};
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
  let _showSplash = localStorage.getItem('init');
  let _lNotif = localStorage.getItem("notification");
  let _lUnreadMessage = localStorage.getItem("messages_unread");

  if(_showSplash){
    if(parseInt(_showSplash) == 0){
      localStorage.removeItem('init');
    }
  }else{
    localStorage.setItem('init', 1);
  }
</script>

<script>
var PHONEGAP = {
        plugins: false,
        platform: false,
        isOffline: false,
        messaging: false,
        notification: _lNotif ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notification")) : []
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    app.initialize();
    console.log(cordova.plugins); //this return **undefined**


  
</script>

<script src="js/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

i'm new to cordova here, so i don't understand why i cant call cordova.plugins inside my svelte app (main.bundle.js).

Also i have tried call cordova object inside svelte app by calling `console.log(cordova)` and it work! i checked the console and it has plugins object inside it but when i call `console.log(cordova.plugins)` it return undefined.

```
cordova version 6.0.0
platformVesion 6.0.0
platformId browser (it has same error too with android platform)
phonegap cli version 9.0.0
```

result of `phonegap plugins`

```
cordova-plugin-androidx 2.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.1 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-battery-status 1.2.5 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.4 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics 4.3.1 "FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging 4.4.2 "FirebaseMessagingPlugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.9 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.3 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.6 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-support-android-plugin 1.0.2 "cordova-support-android-plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.4.1 "cordova-support-google-services"
```

result of `console.log(cordova)`

```
 {version: "6.0.0", platformVersion: "6.0.0", platformId: "browser", define: ƒ, require: ƒ, …}
    InAppBrowser: {open: ƒ}
    addConstructor: ƒ (func)
    addDocumentEventHandler: ƒ (event)
    addStickyDocumentEventHandler: ƒ (event)
    addWindowEventHandler: ƒ (event)
    callbackError: ƒ (callbackId, args)
    callbackFromNative: ƒ (callbackId, isSuccess, status, args, keepCallback)
    callbackId: 1855496235
    callbackStatus: {NO_RESULT: 0, OK: 1, CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION: 2, ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION: 3, INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION: 4, …}
    callbackSuccess: ƒ (callbackId, args)
    callbacks: {}
    commandProxy: {add: ƒ, remove: ƒ, get: ƒ}
    define: ƒ (id, factory)
    exec: ƒ (success, fail, service, action, args)
    file: {applicationDirectory: "http://localhost:3000/", applicationStorageDirectory: null, dataDirectory: "filesystem:file:///persistent/", cacheDirectory: "filesystem:file:///temporary/", externalApplicationStorageDirectory: null, …}
    fireDocumentEvent: ƒ (type, data, bNoDetach)
    fireWindowEvent: ƒ (type, data)
    getOriginalHandlers: ƒ ()
    platformId: "browser"
    platformVersion: "6.0.0"
    plugins: {firebase: {…}}
    removeDocumentEventHandler: ƒ (event)
    removeWindowEventHandler: ƒ (event)
    require: ƒ (id)
    version: "6.0.0"
    __proto__: Object
```

**edit**
the problem here is when i call `console.log(cordova)` the result object has **plugins** object inside it, but when i call `console.log(cordova.plugins)` it return **undefined** (all is called inside main index.html file).

Comment: where do you call `console.log(cordova.plugins)` in index.html? I don't see it..

Comment: Sorry i edit my code, the console.log is in index.html and also index.js(onDeviceReady), in index.html `cordova.plugins` return _undefined_ but in index.js (onDeviceReady) it return all plugins object ( {firebase:(...)} like so )

Comment: Ok so it it is as I thought, it's probably because at this point, `app.initialize()` has bound the `deviceready` event, but it hasn't fired yet. Your plugins will only be there when the event has fired. You need to ensure that `deviceready` is the starting point of your code execution

Comment: Yes, my thougt exactly, but i already mention i'm new to cordova/phonegap, i dont exactly understand how to wait cordova plugins to be ready (and then initialize the svelte app after that), my last attempt is move the svelte initialize code to onDeviceReady function, but the svelte app is fail to initialize although the device ready is called.

`onDeviceReady: function(){const svelteApp = new SvelteApp({...});}`

Comment: FYI, i already create new cordova project with default setting (`cordova create <project_name>` add platform browser and android and then add some plugin(cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging) but the error is still same, `cordova.plugins` return undefined when i called in index.html (after `app.initialize()`), but when i called in index.js (inside onDeviceReady) it return object with plugins inside it.

Comment: The thing is I know nothing about svelte, i can give you one or two better ways to pass a callback to be called when `deviceready` is fired, but I don't know it this will fit your case

Comment: Yes please i think i need it, for now i just want to call cordova.plugins outside deviceready callback.

Answer (score -1):

To make svelte works with cordova(cordova.plugins), i must wrap the svelte initialization code inside `onDeviceReady`(deviceready events)

main.js (inside svelte src)

```
import "./main.pcss";
import App from './App.svelte';

function onDeviceReady(){
    new App({
        target: document.body,
        hydrate: true
    });
}
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

As result, i can finally access to cordova plugins inside my svelte app

App.svelte

```
import { cordovaObject } from "./store.js";
.....
console.log(cordova.plugins); //just for testing, finally it works!
cordovaObject.set(cordova); //save cordova object inside store
.....
```

after that i can save the `cordova` object inside store, then i can use all the plugins i want.
Of course, i didn't think this is good or bad solution, but at least it working for now.